# Optimal Strategy Game for making SOS

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

There are 2 players in the game, each having characters S and O. There are n gaps, Each player on his turn would place either S or O character in  one of the gaps. Player who makes SOS first would win. We have to find who would win the game with n gaps, given that player 1 plays first and both the players play with most optimal strategy. 
For Example consider n = 7. 
Player 1: _ _ _ S _ _ _
Player 2: O _ _ S _ _ _
Player 1: O _ _ S _ _ S
PLayer 2: O O _ S _ _ S
Player 1: O O O S _ _ S
Player 2: O O O S S _ S
Player 1: O O O S S O S

Player 1 would always win when n = 7.

Answer (score 3):

Player 1 should make S _ _ S, and wait for player 2 to enter anything in 2 remaining slots. Whatever and wherever player 2 does in his turn player 1 has a winning move in his turn. This means first move must be S in the middle.

The setup for the win takes several turns, and in the mean time Player 2 may try to make SOS on its own. Player 1 must detect that there is available SOS to be made, and use current turn to win prematurely.

Comment: I just realized I was answering another question, how to win as Player 1 on 7 gaps, instead of who would win given n gaps and perfect players. My bad.